# Custom list view filter not working in mobile view

Tags: filter

I had to filter sharepoint list view dynamically with n number of conditions so I have written the code in PageHead delegate control. Everything works fine on browser but when I try to check the same page in mobile view it says cannot complete action.

I had debug to see the issue and have found the delegate control is not getting called for mobile view.

Can someone please assist as to how I can execute delegate control in mobile view also??